# Reassign mailbox to another user

Tags: exchange, microsoft-office-365

Quite frequently, our clients on Office 365 have an employee leave, but would still like to have access to their email.

What's the best way to give access to another user, while still disabling or deleting the user account and the email address?

Answer (score 1):

I would go with a Shared Mailbox.

Once you convert it you can remove the user, and his user object and license are removed from Office 365.  You can change the SMTP address of the mailbox and remove the old SMTP alias, or use auto respond rules, or transport rules to manage new incoming mail to that old address.

**Edit**

Ok - so you are synced to AD then.  That changes things a bit.  What is probably happening is when sync runs the mailbox is changed back to user mailbox, and then it goes thru the decommissioning process.

The "official" way to do this is:

1. Migrate mailbox back to Exchange
2. Convert it to Shared Mailbox
3. Migrate back to Exchange Online
4. Remove license from user

But you can try to this (Unsupported)

1. Convert mailbox to shared in O365
2. Edit the user object and modify the msExchangeRemoteRecipienttype to 97 with ADSIEdit
3. Sync back to O365
4. Remove license / user.

I've not tested the above - but I do now this attribute is set when creating the shared mailbox on-prem and then migrating up. Pretty sure it's the only one you need, but it's possible there are one or two more that have to be set.

Comment: You could also just restrict delivery to only `authenticated senders`, if it was desired to only turn off the email account to the outside world.

Comment: That's actually exactly what I did. I converted the mailbox to shared, then deleted the user from the 365 side. But then the shared mailbox disappeared too. Restoring the user brought it back as a shared mailbox. Do I need to disconnect it from the user somehow?